# How can I insert data in oracle sql developer from already created tables

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

I am currently trying to input data into one of my tables but links to another table in the database, the code below is what I have found but it keeps putting in null, what am I missing or am I doing it all wrong?

```
INSERT INTO VOLUNTEER(VOLUNTEERID,membershipid,MEMBERNAME,MEMBERDAYTIMENO)
VALUES (1, 
       (SELECT MEMBERSHIPID FROM MEMBERSHIP WHERE MEMBERNAME = 'FRANCES'),
       (SELECT MEMBERNAME FROM MEMBERSHIP WHERE MEMBERNAME = 'FRANCES'),
       (SELECT MEMBERDAYTIMENO FROM MEMBERSHIP WHERE MEMBERNAME ='FRANCES')
);
```

I am using Oracle SQL Database.

Comment: what is the result if you run: SELECT MEMBERSHIPID FROM MEMBERSHIP WHERE MEMBERNAME = 'FRANCES'

Comment: nothing even though there is data in that table @AdrianNasui

Comment: there's your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I was calling the wrong information so I now have fixed it

```
INSERT INTO VOLUNTEER(VOLUNTEERID,membershipid,MEMBERNAME,MEMBERDAYTIMENO)
VALUES (2, (SELECT MEMBERSHIPID FROM MEMBERSHIP WHERE MEMBERSHIPID = 2),
   (SELECT MEMBERNAME FROM MEMBERSHIP WHERE MEMBERSHIPID = 2),
   (SELECT MEMBERDAYTIMENO FROM MEMBERSHIP WHERE MEMBERSHIPID = 2));
```

thanks for your answers though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO VOLUNTEER(VOLUNTEERID, membershipid, MEMBERNAME, MEMBERDAYTIMENO)
   SELECT                       1, MEMBERSHIPID, MEMBERNAME, MEMBERDAYTIMENO
      FROM MEMBERSHIP WHERE MEMBERNAME = 'FRANCES';
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is at all similar to mySQL this is what you want:

```
INSERT INTO VOLUNTEER(VOLUNTEERID,membershipid,MEMBERNAME,MEMBERDAYTIMENO)
  SELECT 1, MEMBERSHIPID, MEMBERNAME, MEMBERDAYTIMENO 
  FROM MEMBERSHIP WHERE MEMBERNAME ='FRANCES';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO VOLUNTEER(VOLUNTEERID,membershipid,MEMBERNAME,MEMBERDAYTIMENO)
SELECT 1, MEMBERSHIPID, MEMBERNAME, MEMBERDAYTIMENO 
  FROM MEMBERSHIP WHERE MEMBERNAME ='FRANCES';
```

If you need to know count of inserted rows, you can use:

```
begin
    INSERT INTO VOLUNTEER(VOLUNTEERID,membershipid,MEMBERNAME,MEMBERDAYTIMENO)
    SELECT 1, MEMBERSHIPID, MEMBERNAME, MEMBERDAYTIMENO 
      FROM MEMBERSHIP WHERE MEMBERNAME ='FRANCES';

    dbms_out.put_line('Rows inserted: ' || sql%rowcount);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

```
SELECT MEMBERSHIPID FROM MEMBERSHIP WHERE MEMBERNAME = 'FRANCES'
```

is returning your relevant data. Seems it is not.